# Storing 2 items in GSI per item in main table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Say I have a dynamo table as:

```
Partition Key: "Partition_Key"
Sort Key: "Sort_Key"
GSI1 Partition Key: "Uuid_Type1"
```

And let us assume full projection.

Say I insert 2 items as below:

Item1

```
"Partition_Key" : "PK1"
"Sort_Key"      : "SK1"
"Uuid_Type1"    : "Uuid11"
```

Item2

```
"Partition_Key" : "PK2"
"Sort_Key"      : "SK2"
"Uuid_Type2"    : "UuidT21"
```

I also understand that when I insert `Item1` my GSI1 will get updated with `Item1`. When I will insert `Item2`, it won't be present in `GSI1`
If I want to fetch based on `Item2's` `Uuid_Type2` and avoid a scan, I can create a separate GSI, say GSI2.

I have read about GSI overloading but I am not sure if in the use case I have, I can find a way to achieve querying on `Uuid_Type1` or `Uuid_Type2` with only single GSI

Comment: I think it would be easier to answer this question if we had some more context.  All we know is you want to use a secondary index to search for items using different attributes.

Are the items or attributes related in any way? Are the `Uuid_Type1` and `Uuid_Type2` fields UUIDs only?  Are they strings with a `type` suffix?

GSI overloading may be a good fit for your problem, but I can't tell from the generic example you've given.  Can you provide more context?

Comment: The 2 attributes are valid UUIDs denoting two separate entities. For example u can say the attributes names can be "myid1" and "myid2". They are not related or hard to do prefix search.